# Are powers less than or equal to zero considered in Newton Sums?

Tags: polynomials, proof-explanation, roots

I was looking at a proof for Newton Sums ([Proof](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Newton%27s_Sums)), and it concludes the following:

[image]

So if you were to have a polynomial with four terms and four non-zero roots the following should be true: $a_3P_1+a_2P_0+a_1P_{-1}+a_0P_{-2} = 0$, but the site claims that $a_3P_1+a_2 = 0$. Are root sums with powers less than or equal to zero not supposed to be considered in the equation? Why is that the case?

Answer (score 1):

A simplified polynomial with four terms has degree $3$. Hence there can only be three non-zero roots. So you would have:
$$a_3P_1+3a_2+a_1P_{-1}+a_0P_{-2}=0.$$
Since $a_3P_1+a_2=0$ (which is a rearrangement of Vieta's formula), we must have:
$$2a_2+a_1P_{-1}+a_0P_{-2}=0.$$
Nothing in the proof indicates that root sums with powers less than or equal to zero cannot be considered.